# VS Code Flask configuration seemingly causing "unable to import module"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

I have a Flask app that works on both macOS and Windows, but there are some "module not found" messages showing in VS Code terminal on Windows (even though the app still works fine in spite of the issues). Seems like something wrong with VS Code configuration?

Note that the /Website is a subfolder of the VS Code project and the VS Code root is one level up, so there is a cwd command in the launch file which perhaps is related to the issue on Windows (but works on macOS).

Here is the terminal output for Windows. The first run is command line entered and works fine.

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Brett\Documents\Development\Project\Website> flask run
Running in production mode
 * Debug mode: off
2023-10-14 12:37:17,733 INFO WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 [_internal.py:_internal:_log:96]
2023-10-14 12:37:17,734 INFO Press CTRL+C to quit [_internal.py:_internal:_log:96]
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Brett\Documents\Development\Project\Website>
```

Here is the output when run from launcher:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Brett\Documents\Development\Project\Website>  C:; cd 'C:\Users\Brett\Documents\Development\Project/Website'; & 'c:\Users\Brett\Documents\Development\Project\Website\.venv\bin\python3.exe' 'c:\Users\Brett\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '58689' '--' '-m' 'flask' 'run' '--no-debugger' '--no-reload'
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Running in debug mode
2023-10-14 12:37:35,973 INFO Logging setup complete [__init__.py:__init__:init_app:62]
 * Serving Flask app 'wsgi.py'
 * Debug mode: on
2023-10-14 12:37:36,002 INFO WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 [_internal.py:_internal:_log:96]
2023-10-14 12:37:36,002 INFO Press CTRL+C to quit [_internal.py:_internal:_log:96]
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Brett\Documents\Development\Project\Website>
```

Here is my VS Code launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Website",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "wsgi.py",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Final piece of info is that I put a breakpoint on entry on "app = init_app()" line in wsgi.py and the messages appear in terminal before the breakpoint is hit. Here is wsgi.py:

```
from application import init_app

app = init_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was I uninstalled all other python installations on my local machine and reinstalled venv. Might be related to seeming change in Python 3.12.

I went to check environment variables and found that I had 3.10 and 3.11 also installed. I removed them and rebooted. Then I deleted my venv and reinstalled it. **Previously the venv had a .venv/bin path and under 3.12 it has a .venv/Scripts path.**

I believe the issue was a different version of python initialized the venv and I choose 3.12 as my interpreter, and so I suspect the messages were coming from the fact that the venv folder was different. Just a guess...

Comment: Hi mr.b, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Will do. It wouldn't let me accept it yet. Still got 58 mins until I can :-)